# How to increment date field by 1 month for each returned row

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I am attempting to alter a view and want to return a column for the first row and then increase each subsequent row by 1 month.

Similar threads have been made but all answers resolve around using `row_number` which results in adding 1XXX months in my testing cause the ID is not starting from 1.

It's a little complicated and will add more information when I get back to a computer. I was investigating `CROSS APPLY` but no luck there yet.

Updated example using some help from answers here:

```sql
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[_uReport_AU_LetterOfOffer_Benefits]
AS
WITH RankedInvoices AS (
    SELECT
        ClientID,
        InvoiceDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY InvoiceDate) - 1 AS RowNumber
    FROM
        tbl_Client_Offer_Reg
)
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
   <big_list_of_fields_here>
   DATEADD(month, RankedInvoices.RowNumber, RankedInvoices.InvoiceDate) AS [COR Invoice Date]

FROM 
   <whole_list_of_inner_and_outer_joins_here>,
   RankedInvoices

GROUP BY 
   <bunch_of_group_bys_here>, RankedInvoices.InvoiceDate, RankedInvoices.RowNumber

HAVING      
   (dbo.tbl_wiseNET_sys_ccmb_ChecklistItem.ChecklistItemType = N'Benefits')
ORDER BY [COR Checklist Date Due], [COR Checklist Desc]
GO
```

This alter statement runs fine but not getting the desired result on the user end when they try to generate a report that calls this view it fails.

Desired result with invoicedate = 10/12/2023:

```
10/12/2023 
10/01/2024
10/02/2024 
10/03/2024 
and so on
```

UPDATE 1:
Was having issues and tried to simplify it to this in the original select instead of having a with()

```
DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), FORMAT(tbl_Client_Offer_Reg_1.InvoiceDate, 'd', 'en-gb')) AS [COR Checklist Invoice Date],
```

Problem now is that `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
is returning and starting with 1729 so its adding that many months!?

```
  1729 
  1730
  1731 
  ...
```

in a fiddle it works fine I think because this is a view and the statement is quite complicated with heaps of joins etc that its doing something strange

Update 2:

Ended up simplifying it to

```
                      FORMAT(DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl_Client_Offer_Reg_1.ClientID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), tbl_Client_Offer_Reg_1.InvoiceDate), 'd', 'en-gb') AS [COR Checklist Invoice Date],
```

and worked fine but issue is when it returns for 2 offers I need to figure out the parititon by and order by clauses i think. When i run the script directly agains the db it works perfectly now but cause its a view it requires some fiddling about

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```sql
WITH RankedInvoices AS (
    SELECT
        A.InvoiceId,
        A.InvoiceDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.InvoiceId ORDER BY A.InvoiceDate) - 1 AS RowNumber
    FROM
        A
)
SELECT
    DATEADD(month, RowNumber, InvoiceDate) AS [Invoice Date]
FROM
    RankedInvoices;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <your_ordering_column>) AS rn
FROM <your_view_name>
)
SELECT <your_initial_field>,
DATEADD(month, rn - 1, <your_initial_date>) AS calculated_date
FROM CTE
```

Replace <your_initial_field> and <your_initial_date> with the actual field name and initial date that you want to use.
Also, replace <your_ordering_column> with the actual column name.